# Placement of the ng-app directive (html vs body)

Tags: angularjs

I recently reviewed the code for a webapp built with angular and found that it was written with the `ng-app="myModule"` directive placed on the `<body>` tag.  When learning angular, I've only ever seen it used on the `<html>` tag, as recommended by the angular docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp), and in their [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00).

I've explored this a bit on my own and found SO questions, notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583289/multi-modules-in-one-page-with-angularjs) and similarly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641730/angular-js-directives-in-different-modules), that discuss loading multiple modules for a page. However, this technique different from my case, as it involves placing ng-app on elements *within* the body and using manual bootstrapping to run two angular apps at the same time.

As far as I can tell, there is no difference at runtime between an app with `ng-app` on `<html>` or `<body>`.  As I understand it, `ng-app` designates the root of an angular application, so placement of it on the `<body>` would cut `<head>` out of angular's scope, but I can't think of any major way this would affect things.  So my question is: What are the technical difference between placing `ng-app` on one of these tags instead of the other?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

There is no big difference where you put `ng-app`.

If you put it on `<body>` then you have a smaller scope for AngularJS which is **slightly** faster.

But I have used `ng-app` on the `<html>` for manipulating the `<title>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  This is basically the conclusion I'd come to, so it's good to hear that others are thinking along the same lines.  I'm interested in exactly why it's faster and how much faster it could be, are you able to explain that more or do you have any references that can illustrate this?

Comment: I really mean __slightly__ faster. It is minimal. Just smaller scope means less elements in which AngularJS to look for directives. If you have a ton of meta elements for Open Graph for example it could have a small impact.

Comment: title. that's the real reason.

Comment: As an aside, placing the ng-app in the body tag is not W3C compliant *UNLESS* you prepend as a custom element.  For example data-ng-app="MyModule".

Comment: I would just use plain javascript to change the title.

Comment: @Sean_A91 if you however have the whole page run by AngularJS it makes more sense to use Angular for that. It's more consistent which increases maintainability and you could reuse the title model in the page body as well.

Answer (score 21):

I was on a team working on a legacy app and found it best to use the ng-app tag in a div that is used as a wrapper to isolate new code from the legacy code.

We discovered this while working on the app that was heavily relying on jqGrid and Dojo.

When we added ng-app to the head tag it blew up the site, but when we used a wrapper we could use Angular with no problems.

Comment: This is a good example of where I differentiate between three use cases for Angular: "single page app", "standalone" (i.e. takes over page but uses normal links to other pages), and "mixin" (i.e. just a small bit on the page). You have described exactly the mixin usage and in that case, totally agreed ng-app should be only on the div where the mixin applies. However, for standalone or SPA usages, I think it should be on the <html>.

Comment: @fool4jesus Do you happen to know any articles about different usage options for Angular? Of course there's a ton about recommended SPA version, but recently I had to add Angular to jQuery-heavy codebase and was wondering what is the best option here to use it with success and not go crazy.

Comment: That can be a tricky one @Senthe. As you've discovered no doubt, angular likes to be in charge of its own DOMain. I think it's less about overlapping areas of the page and more about control of that area. That is, you can still use the jquery in the angular areas, but start with the angular code - not easy when the page already exists! In other words, it's not the jquery calls that have to go, as much as the stuff between the <script> tags has to move into angular constructs - controllers and directives. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 4):

AngularJS will bootstrap the first ng-app it finds! That's it. If you have more than one ng-app, it will only process the first one. If you want to bootstrap any other element use angular.bootstrap()

The value of the ng-app attribute is a module that have been created using:

```
angular.module("module_name", [])
```

A module defines how angular will bootstrapped because we do not have a main() method unlike other programming languages. If ng-app's value is empty, then it defaults to use 'ng', the default module.

It was said to be slightly faster because angular will process all of the elements inside the element where ng-app was. But I doubt slightly part because the difference will be hardly noticeable at all, unless you have a very very bulky DOM.

If you want examples here: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/07/angularjs-tutorials-understanding.html