# ngRoute not working while no errors are reported to console

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I built a simple app which is having following pages.

1) index.html

2) View1.html

3) View2.html

The problem I am facing is while routing the the app to View1 and View2. No output is displayed and the browser. After some reseach I realised that from Angular version 1.2 onwards, seperate "angular-route.js" file needs to be included which I did but got no help. Can you pls look into this and provide solution.

PS: I am new to Angular so pls spare me if I have made a any small mistakes.

Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <!--Placeholder for Views-->
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);

        demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){

        //demoApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

                    $routeProvider
                    .when('/view1',{
                           controller: 'SimpleController',
                           templateurl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                     })

                     .when('/view2',{
                           controller: 'SimpleController',
                           templateurl: 'Partials/View1.html'
                     })

                     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1'});
        });

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [ 
                 {name:'John Smith', city:'Phoenix'},
                 {name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},
                 {name:'Jane Doe', city:'San Fancisco'}
            ];

            $scope.addCustomer = function() {
              $scope.customers.push(
                      {
                          name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                          city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                      });
                 }; 
            });

       </script>
</body>
```

**View1.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:city "> {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase }}</li>
</ul>

<br /> 
Customer Name:<br /> 
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
<br />
Customer City:<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
<br /><br />
<button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
<br /><br />
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
```

**View2.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
City:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="city" />
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:name "> {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: The routing of view2 redirects to 'Partials/View1.html', minor error I guess. Check out the console as @Pankaj Parkar said and tell us if there's anything there

Answer (score 6):

The typo:

```
templateurl: 'Partials/View1.html'
```

should be

```
templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
```

Angular is not going to load anything since no template is provided.

Comment: @dfsq - worked like a charm

Comment: @Rajat Cool, feel free to accept the answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove ng-app from html tag and add it in body tag.

Comment: Should do exactly the same as having it in the html tag

Comment: You are using the tag before its definition from angular file gets loaded.

Comment: take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790432/placement-of-the-ng-app-directive-html-vs-body

Comment: ... or documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: thank you david for your suggestion but now i am curious to understand more on this. i have some queries. 1] when you add jquery.js file after angular.js file in script tag it gives error. 2] considering same before loading angular.js file how can we call a angular directive.

Comment: I've used in both tags and it works but I'm not sure about these queries, it is a great question, why don't you publish it so that someone can give us an answer?

Comment: sure david.. I have been following my understanding and never tried to use it in html tag. i will try one example if i could get answer on this else i will put question . thank you david

Comment: No problem, count with my upvote on your question!