# what is difference between writing ng-app in <html> tag and <body> tag?

Tags: html, angularjs

we can write **`ng-app`** in any html tag.

But what is the difference if we write it in **`<html>`** or **`<body>`** or **`<head>`**.

Please help me out.

Comment: Already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790432/placement-of-the-ng-app-directive-html-vs-body

Comment: Refer this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790432/placement-of-the-ng-app-directive-html-vs-body

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you put `ng-app` it doesn't matter.

`ng-app`  enables angular environment within it's block.

like if you use `ng-app` in `head` tag then it'll enable angular environment within it's `</head>` tag.

Like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <div ng-app>
    {{4+5}} <!-- inside of ng-app block -->
  </div>

  <div>
    {{4+5}} <!-- outside of ng-app block -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrapping of your application begins from the element where you declare the attribute

```
data-ng-app
```