# What is the role of ng-app directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS. Now I am trying to write a simple angular application. But I am wondering the role of the `ng-app` directive.

```
<html ng-app>
```

And is it possible to add `ng-app` in a `div` tag instead of `html` tag? If possible, is there any differences between `<html ng-app>` and `<div ng-app>`, for example, the operating efficiency ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp I think the question is worthless... should be cancelled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placement of the ng-app directive (html vs body)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790432/placement-of-the-ng-app-directive-html-vs-body)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ng-app` directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the `<body>` or `<html>` tags.You can only have one `ng-app` directive in your HTML document.It is also used to load various AngularJS modules in AngularJS Application. The AngularJS framework will only process the DOM elements and its child elements where the `ng-app` directive is applied

Usage

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-app` directive is for bootstrapping your application.

The element with `ng-app` is the **root element**: it wraps the other directives of your application.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div controller="ctrl"></div> <!-- working -->
</div>
<div controller="myOtherCtrl"></div> <!-- not working -->
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):

> **Directive Usage**
>
> as attribute:
>
> `<ANY   ng-app="angular.Module"   [ng-strict-di="boolean"]> ... </ANY>`

So you can add `ng-app` on a `div` or any other element.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-app` attribute represents an Angular directive named `ngApp` (Angular uses `spinal-case` for its custom attributes and `camelCase` for the corresponding directives which implement them). This directive is used to flag the html element that Angular should consider to be the root element of our application. This gives application developers the freedom to tell Angular if the entire html page or only a portion of it should be treated as the Angular application.

Thus, you can add `ng-app` in the div tag.